# VGA not working

Tags: display, dell, intel-graphics, monitor, vga

> TL;DR: Connecting notebook to an external monitor with VGA doesn't work,
> Ubuntu recognizes an "unknown" display but nothing appears in the
> monitor. The monitor works on other computers.

I'm trying to use two separate monitors on my notebook, one using the HDMI output and the other the VGA output.

Currently, only the HDMI works and when I connect the VGA cable, Ubuntu recognizes a display but says it's unknown and the monitor itself doesn't detect any output. I can move the mouse to this "phantom" monitor, but the monitor doesn't show anything.

I confirmed that even if a user only the VGA output it still doesn't work and the monitor itself works using HDMI and using the VGA on another computer. It seems that the problem is the VGA connection itself.

I tried looking up for solutions, but nothing worked for me.

Does anyone here know how to solve this or what can I do to further investigate the problem?

- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Though it didn't work in the previous version as
  well)
- Monitor: p2319h
- Cable: VGA
- Notebook: Dell Latitude 3400 Graphic
- Card: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) (rev 02)

`xrandr` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4950 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+312 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1366x768      60.06*+  48.05  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 connected 2560x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 673mm x 284mm
   2560x1080     60.00*+
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 connected 1024x768+3926+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was resolved by:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```